# How do I capture a ToolBarItem tap?

Tags: xamarin.ios, tabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with four (4) TabBarItems... how do I address each TabBarItem so I can capture the tapped event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wire up a delegate to the *ViewControllerSelected* event on your UITabBarController to handle tab selection changes.  The event args (UITabBarSelectionEventArgs) include the ViewController which was selected and from there you can do your processing albeit in a slightly inverted way.